# cant launch webOS eclipse IDE

Tags: ide, webos

I'm new to webOS SDK. Downloaded the installer and after i finished installation couldn't launch IDE.

I also tried to install from offline package. But still same.

Keep freezing at this screen.

MacOS 10.12.6 
java version "1.8.0_131"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You must run with sudo. Try run with command like this

> sudo /Users/USER/webOS_TV_SDK/IDE/WebOSIDE.app/Contents/MacOS/WebOSIDE ; exit;

Answer (score 0):

Do the following :

1. Delete the following old config files:

   - C:\Users[User Name]\AppData\Roaming.webos
   - C:\Users[User Name]\AppData\Roaming.ares
2. Re-start webOS TV IDE.